# CSG - Boolean operation using a CSG.Plane

Tags: javascript, boolean, subtraction, plane, csg

I can define a `CSG.Plane` with a `normal` and a constant `w` like this:

```
CSG.Plane = function(normal, w) {
    this.normal = normal;
    this.w = w;
};
```

How can I now use this CSG plane in a boolean `subtract` operation?

I think I have to somehow convert the plane to a `CSG.Node`, but I don't know how to do without having any vertices...

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using CSG.JS. If that is correct you can't do CSG operations with a plane because the operations assume a closed mesh. Its an attractive option to use a plane to clip a mesh but it doesn't work. I've been working on this issue myself and will be creating a giant box to do the operation.